# Facebook AppRequest can't show any friend in Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I use Facebook official Unity SDK to run in Unity Editor ios platform

After FB login,I press "Open Friend Selector"

and it show a dialog

but I don't know why it doesn't show any friend in dialog,

because I have one friend in FB.

My FB.Login permission include "read_friendlists,email,publish_actions,user_friends"

Anyone know why it can't show one friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Unity app in the Facebook Console is not set to be available to the public, I don't think you can see real friend because none of your real friends will be able to log in to your app, so they won't be included.

This [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) states:

> The list of friends is no longer part of the default list of
>   permissions ***and only returns the friends using the app***.

Before making your app available to the public, you can add your friend as a test user under the Settings > Roles screen in the Facebook Console. Then they can log in to your app, and you can see them as a friend in your app.

You can create test users, and set them to be friends of each other. Then you can log in to your Unity Facebook app with a test user access token. You should then see the test friends listed.